# What is the Linux scsi mid-layer

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, drivers

In the Linux storage stack there are 3 levels: upper, mid and lower.  Therefore, I know *what* it is in that sense.  What I'm hoping someone will know is, what files in the Linux source tree *actually comprise* the storage (scsi) mid-layer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a linux kernel doc about the ["midlayer_implementation"](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/scsi/mid_layer.html)

> ```
> SCSI midlayer implementation
>
>     include/scsi/scsi_device.h
>     drivers/scsi/scsi.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsicam.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_error.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_devinfo.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_ioctl.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_lib.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_lib_dma.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_module.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_proc.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_netlink.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_scan.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_sysctl.c
>     drivers/scsi/scsi_sysfs.c
>     drivers/scsi/hosts.c
>     drivers/scsi/constants.c
> ```

Comment: Sorry it took 4 years to get back to this.  Why was this down-voted?  It looks entirely like this is the answer to my question.  Oh, and thanks for the link.

Comment: Welcome back:p. If I remember it correctly, my very first anwser was only a link and someone reminded me that I need to quote the content to avoid a potential deadlink.